# Unit-testing React Components using Context Consumers

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-context

I used to have component that looked like this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Foo">
                <div id="user">Bar</div>
                <SomeOtherComponent />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and this test:

```
it('renders a help button', () => {
  expect(shallow(<Foo />).find('#user').length).toEqual(1);
});
```

But now I have added a context consumer to this object:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Consumer>
                {({user}) => (
                    <div className="Foo">
                        <div id="user">{user}</div>
                        <SomeOtherComponent />
                    </div>
                )}
            </UserContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I test the following conditions?

- The amount of "#user" is 1
- The user displayed is the one provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock `UserContext.Consumer` to render with a certain hardcoded user. Not sure how you export `UserContext`, but it would look something like this:

```
jest.mock('path/to/UserContextModule', () => ({
  UserContext: {
    Consumer: ({children}) => children({user: 'User'})
  }
}))
```

And the rest of your test would remain the same.

Comment: also, if it's shallow, you might have to `.dive()`

Comment: Not the hero I deserved, but the hero I needed.